# Integrate 1/x over polar curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Completely stumped on this question:

> Integrate $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}$ over the region bounded by the curve $r=2\cos(\theta)$ for $0
>  \le \theta \le \pi/2$

I tried the usual plug and chug $x=r\cos\left(\theta\right)$ giving $\frac{1}{r\cos(\theta)}$ and then tried to integrate it $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{2} \frac{1}{r\cos(\theta)} r\,dr\,d\theta$$

I know I'm doing something wrong because the bound for $r$ should have something to do with the intersection of the region with the surface but this is unlike anything I've ever seen. I feel like there should be a sine in there, somewhere since $f$ is a 3-d function.

I think $f$ is a surface with a level curve in the $xz$ plane $z=1/x$ extending infinitely in the $y$ direction? Not sure how this helps, though.

Comment: Sure r cancels, but once you integrate by r it comes back.   Your upper bound for r should be $2\cos\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\cos\theta} \sec\theta \,dr d\theta\\ 
\int r \sec\theta d\theta |_0^{2\cos\theta}\\ 
\int_0^{\pi/2} 2 d\theta\\
\pi 
$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had the idea in my mind that r could not be bounded at 0 since 1/x is undefined at 0. What is the logic for bounding r at 0? Is it because $2cosθ$ can take 0 as a value? Doesn't this just calculate the area of r from 0 to π/2?

Comment: yes 1/x is going off to infinity, but it is such a small area above the disk that the integral can still converge.